# How do I filter with multiple classes?

Tags: jquery, filter

I want to filter divs and their sub-groups.
I have a solution from another post but I want the current selection to 'uncheck'.
For instance, if I select 'cars' then 'blue' I will see blue cars. But I currently have to deselect blue to view the red cars. I have the same issue switching from 'cars' to 'buses'.
Hope my question makes sense. Here is what I am currently working with.

```
<body>
<div>
  <button class="filter-button" type="button" data-filter="all">Show all</button>
  <button class="filter-button" type="button" data-filter="car">car</button>
  <button class="filter-button" type="button" data-filter="bus">bus</button>
</div>
<div>
  <button class="filter-button" type="button" data-filter="all">Show all</button>
  <button class="filter-button" type="button" data-filter="red">Red</button>
  <button class="filter-button" type="button" data-filter="blue">Blue</button>
</div>

<div>
  <p class="filter car red">Red Car</p>
  <p class="filter car blue">Blue Car</p>
  <p class="filter bus red">Red Bus</p>
  <p class="filter bus blue">Blue Bus</p>
</div>
</body>

$(document).ready(function(){
    var targets = $('.filter'),
    buttons = $('.filter-button');
    buttons.click(function(){
        var value = $(this).data('filter');
        if(value == "all")
        {
            buttons.removeClass('checked');
            targets.show('1000');
        }
        else
        {
            if($(this).hasClass('checked'))
            {
                $(this).removeClass('checked');
                var checkedClasses = buttons.filter('.checked').toArray().map(function(btn){return $(btn).data('filter');});
                if(checkedClasses.length == 0)
                {
                    buttons.removeClass('checked');
                    targets.show('1000');
                }
                else
                {
                    checkedClasses = $.grep(checkedClasses, function(n, i){ return n != value }),
                    selector = '.' + checkedClasses.join('.'),
                    show = targets.filter(selector);
                    targets.not(show).hide('3000');
                    show.show('3000');
                }
            }
            else
            {
                $(this).addClass('checked');
                var checkedClasses = buttons.filter('.checked').toArray().map(function(btn){return $(btn).data('filter');}),
                selector = '.' + checkedClasses.join('.'),
                show = targets.filter(selector);
                targets.not(show).hide('3000');
                show.show('3000');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Use 2x radio groups (2 lots of 3) and style them like buttons, then read the filter from the radio groups each time rather than rely on previous selections.

Comment: Update: looks like you're already doing something similar by adding `checked` (class) to the button then building the filter from all checked buttons.   You add `$(this).closest("div").find(".checked").removeClass("checked")` to clear all the filters in "group" (then add the one you've clicked on).